# Javascript search box with select option

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a custom search box for our website. Got it working as below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bookssearch(bs) {
    window.open('http://webpac.kdu.edu.my/search/query?match_1=MUST&field_1=title&term_1=' + bs + '&facet_loc=20000&sort=relevance&theme=kdu', 'bswindow');
  }
</script>
Title:
<br />
<form onsubmit="bookssearch(this.bs.value); return false;">
  <input type="text" name="bs" size="30" placeholder="Enter book title.." />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  <br />
</form>
```

Now, I want to add options into **field_1=** so that user can select before proceed with search term which is (bs).
Option into **field_1=** such as:
*Title
Author
Publisher*

This is what i got so far..but its not working. (Please bear with me as I got ZERO knowledge regarding javascript not to mention formal education). All I got here from reading online and stackoverflow of course.. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/btcdfsbm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add options so that user can select before proceeding with search then I thing this will help. Here you are getting the value of your search box and option(select) by its id. So with the values you get you can proceed with your search operation. I hope it helps you :)

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false">
  Term :<br />
  <input name="term_1" size="38" maxlength="50" value="" id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter search term.."><br />
  <select name="field_1" id="option">
    <option value="t" selected="selected">Title</option>
    <option value="a">Author</option>
    <option value="s">Subject</option>
    <option value="call_number">Call Number</option>
    <option value="p">Publisher</option>
  </select>

  <input value="Submit"  type="button" onclick=search()>
  <input value="Reset" type="reset">
</form>

<script>
function search()
{
   var search_input=document.getElementById("searchbox").value;// value of search box
   var option=document.getElementById("option").value; //value of select

   window.open('http://webpac.kdu.edu.my/search/query?match_1=MUST&field_1=' + option + '&term_1=' + search_input + '&facet_loc=20000&sort=relevance&theme=kdu', 'bswindow');   //proceed with search
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After this I want to try to do customization to my search box. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `input` to `select`

```html
<select name="bs">
  <option>Enter book title..</option>
  <option value="value1">option1</option>
  <option value="value2">option2</option>
  <!-- . . . -->
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, im so sorry that I missed look my question. I have edit it. Please help check.